# MongoID throwing wrong number of arguments for any exception. Ruby 3.0.0 + Rails 6.1.3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

My stack is

Ruby 3.0.0
Rails 6.1.3.1
Mongoid 7.1.2

Mongo is throwing always the same exception when should raise others:

`ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2))`

For example:

I have a uniqueness validation for field:

```
irb(main):010:0> Model.create!(field: 'sape')
=> #<Model _id: 606207343dcde26a1595eb48, created_at: 2021-03-29 16:58:28.006091 UTC, updated_at: 2021-03-29 16:58:28.006091 UTC, field: "sape">

irb(main):011:0> Model.create!(field: 'sape')
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):11:in `<main>'
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2))
```

Same for find_by:
If the response founds one, it retrieves it:

```
irb(main):012:0> Model.find_by(field: 'sape')
=> #<Model _id: 606207343dcde26a1595eb48, created_at: 2021-03-29 16:58:28.006 UTC, updated_at: 2021-03-29 16:58:28.006 UTC, field: "sape">
```

But if it does not exists:

```
irb(main):001:0> Model.find_by(field: 'sape')
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1:in `<main>'
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1))
```

This is my Model:

```
class Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Updated

  field :field, type: String, default: nil

  index({ field: 1 }, { unique: true })
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby 3 is not supported by Mongoid at this time and should not be used.

You can see which Rubies Mongoid supports [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-installation/#ruby-compatibility).

Comment: Thanks for your response, is there any mapper you would suggest that supports ruby 3?

Comment: The driver doesn't support Ruby 3 either. Unless you are looking to contribute the support I suggest using Ruby 2.

Comment: It seems that it is still not supported as of today. I was having the same issue and once I moved to Ruby 2.7 the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

update the mongoid gem and it will be fixed

`gem 'mongoid', '~> 7.3.0'`